# Convex function, Epigraph, Sublevel set

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The following graph represents the sublevel set $ S_{-1} = \{(x,y):f(x,y)\le-1\} $ (this is not an epigraph!). Is the function $ f(x,y)=-2e^{x} +y$ convex? Is it quasiconvex? Explain based on the graph.

[image]

I know that the difference between an epigraph and a sublevel set is that an epigraph like the function is part of $\Bbb R^3$ and a sublevel set part of $\Bbb R^2$.

$ -2e^{x} +y\le-1 $

$ y\le2e^{x}-1 $

So, this is the graph of $ -2e^{x} +y=-1 $

The represented sublevel set is not convex and the function is neither convex. Is that correct?

Can I say that the function is not convex, because if 
$f$ is a convex function $\Rightarrow$ it's level sets are convex?
This not here the case.

I know that if:

1. $f$ is convex $\Leftarrow\Rightarrow$ $epi f$ is a convex level set
2. $f$ is convex $\Rightarrow$ all $S_{k}$ sublevel sets must be convex.

Comment: Your point #2 implies that this function is not convex, because it has a sublevel set which is not convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sublevel sets of a convex function are convex.  The shaded region is the intersection of a sublevel set with a convex set; it is not convex, therefore the sublevel set is not convex, therefore the function is not convex.

Comment: Why do you say it's the intersection, is it not just the sublevel set?

Comment: It's not the whole sublevel set, it's just the part with $-2 \le x \le 0$ and $-1 \le y \le 1$.  The rest is outside the picture.

Comment: Okay, but this is really a technicality due to our inability to graph literally all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Undoubtedly the reason the sublevel set is "cutoff" here is just to preserve the marks on the axes and due to limitations on space. I don't see people make this distinction for virtually any other plots.

Comment: Actually, whenever you try to draw conclusions from a plot, you often need to consider whether there is something outside the region being plotted that would change the conclusion.